# Visual Studio Code running Go exec.Command() times out with "kubectl version"

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, kubectl

I'm trying to execute some `kubectl` commands in a Golang application in Visual Studio Code v1.47.1.

The code I am currently using is the following :

```golang
out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "kubectl").Output()

if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to execute")
        fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(out))
```

This is executed just fine, and the output is similar to what appears in a shell on my machine.

However, I would like to execute the command `kubectl version`. Therefore, I tried to update the first line with the code :

- `out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "kubectl version").Output()`
- `out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "kubectl", "version").Output()`
- `out, err := exec.Command("kubectl", "version").Output()`
- `out, err := exec.Command("kubectl version").Output()`

All those tries result in the execution to fail after a timeout of ~10 seconds. `kubectl version` works fine in an external shell.

I also should note that I am able to execute other tools, like `out, err := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "pluto", "version").Output()` without issue.

What is wrong with my approach ?

**EDIT** : I am developing and running my program with the built-in terminal of Visual Studio Code v1.47.1. As it turns out, using an external terminal to launch my program executes the commands without any problem. I need however to know what difference between the built-in VS Code terminal and a standard shell may explain this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, by using the integrated terminal of Visual Studio Code, the environment variables can't be retrieved from an external shell.
More specifically, the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable needed for the `kubectl` commands to be successfully executed is missing.

To solve this issue, environment variables can be defined while using `exec.Command()`:

```golang
KUBECONFIG := "/Users/path_to_kubeconfig/kubeconfig.yaml"

cmd_config := exec.Command("/bin/bash","-c", cmd)
cmd_config.Env = os.Environ()
cmd_config.Env = append(cmd_config.Env, "KUBECONFIG="+ KUBECONFIG)
out, err := cmd_config.Output()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to execute command")
}

fmt.Println(string(out))
```